# Создание и назначение горячих клавиш в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, hotkeys

Допустим, на форме есть два Label и две кнопки. Каким образом можно назначить горячие клавиши, чтобы, например, Ctrl+A активировала процедуру первой кнопки, а CTRL+S второй?

Пытался решить задачу следующим образом:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (chr(Key) in ['A', 'a']) then
   form1.Button1Click(nil);
end;
```

Но, к сожалению, безуспешно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

const
    ID = WM_USER + 1;

type
  Tform_Test = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey); message WM_HOTKEY;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  form_Test: Tform_Test;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tform_Test.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RegisterHotKey(Handle, ID, MOD_CONTROL, Ord('S'));
 // здесь указываешь свою комбинацию клавиш

end;

procedure Tform_Test.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnregisterHotkey(Handle, ID);
end;

procedure Tform_Test.WMHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey);
begin
  if Msg.HotKey = ID then
    Button1Click(nil);
end;

procedure Tform_Test.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello');
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое -- сделать главное меню, а в нем вешать горячие клавиши (и запускать любые процедуры).

Что касается вашего метода, то смотрите у формы  KeyPreview (http://www.delphi.int.ru/articles/106/)

Для дальнейшего развития читай:

http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2375

http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0601_3.htm

http://delphi-z.ru/componfull-41.html

http://delphi-prg.ru/komponent-delphi-hotkey-goryachie-klavishi

Comment: Можно использовать компонент ActionList.
В нём можно прописать действия кнопок, иконки, горячие клавиши, а в свойстве Action самих кнопок указывать эти действия.

Answer (score 0):

[@metalfanat](/users/31470/metalfanat), всё правильно ты пытался, просто ты не активировал, а вызвал.
Для активации просто назначай обработчик

```
Button1.onClick:=form1.Button1Click;
```

Который или при создании формы деактивируешь или изначально не назначаешь.

Comment: <pre>procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (chr(Key) in ['A', 'a']) then
   Button1.onClick:=form1.Button1Click;
end;<code>
Если так, то не работает.

Comment: работает. просто под "активировать код" я понял назначить код обработки события... Если до этого при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходило, то после горячей клавиши, при нажатии на кнопку будет что-то выполняться. А вообще хук из примера ниже лучше используй, так правильнее и меньше будет проблемм...

Answer (score 0):

1) В свойствах формы form1 через Object Inspector нужно указать KeyPreview=True
без этого ваш код отрабатываться не будет.

> KeyPreview - если свойство установлено в True, то при нажатии клавиш
>   сначала будут вызываться обработчики формы, а только затем обработчики
>   того компонента, который в данный момент имеет фокус ввода. События,
>   связанные с нажатием клавиш - OnKeyDown(), OnKeyPress(), OnKeyUp().

2) логику вызова процедур по нажатию клавиш лучше перенести в событие формы form1.OnKeyUp() - "отжатие", а не нажатие